# When zoomed with UIScrollView, it is impossible to scroll properly to the lower end

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, swift4

In order to understand correctly, I prepared a movie.

In this movie, I want to scroll to the red line.

However, it seems that contentSize is not enough.

How can I make it possible to scroll to the red line?

-Code-

```
import UIKit

class PlotterCanvasView: UIView, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    class func instance() -> PlotterCanvasView {
        return UINib(nibName: "PlotterCanvasView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! PlotterCanvasView
    }

    func initValue(){
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0

        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "col")
    }

    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return self.imageView
    }

}
```

-Movie-

[Movie in Youtube](https://youtu.be/jD0gNhMHmlk)
(About movie.
I wrote the above code, and zoom UIImageView in UIScrollView.
However, contentSize is not enough and I can not scroll down to the bottom.)

-Image in xcode-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved my self.

It was possible with constraints like the image below.

(The UIScrollView constraint is "Margin all 0s")
(UIImageView constraint is "Equal Height" for UIScrollView)

[image]